# Cut to beginning/end of line, paste over to end/beginning of line

Tags: vim, viemu

If I am in the middle of a line, how to I cut to the beginning/end of a line? (is copy different)

If I am in the middle of a line, how do I paste over to the beg/end of the line? (is pasting w/o copying over the text much different?)

thanks allot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Yoda said:

1. `d$` cuts to the end of the line
2. `d0` cuts to the beginning
3. `d^` cuts to first non-whitespace character

To paste over the 'head' of the line:

```
v^p
```

or

```
v0p
```

To make it remember the default register, you could use the `_` unnamed register:

```
v$"_p
```

Note that in that case, the *overwritten* text is 'forgotten' instead of yanked. (By default replacing a visual selection effectively yanks the overwritten text, so you can *put* it somewhere else)

Comment: @yoda: well, only if that's not _your_ upvote :) Otherwise, it's just a guess

Comment: well, that is mine... should I take it away? ;)

Comment: ok it is deleting the white space at the beginning of the line which I don't want (like tabbing etc)

Comment: @codecompleting: not if you use the correct variant (choose `0` (include whitespace) or `^` (only till first non-whitespace character of the line)) **Edit** Huh - I just noticed that the post didn't say `^` but `$` :) sry. Updated answer now

Comment: edited the comment to add `dG` to cut to end of file.